# How to send Sensor Output signlas to Long distnaces?

Tags: rs422

In want to interface Incremental encoder sensor output to Microcontroller which is **10 meters** away from the sensor.

Specifications:

Sensor Output : Square wave 0V to 5V , 100KHz frequency.

Controller: F28M35H52C, Interface Module: EQEP (Enhanced Qudrature Encoder Pulses)

As per my understanding, the available options are:

1. Convert sensor output to differential ended signals using RS422/LVDS etc....
2. Convert sensor output to differential ended signals using OP Amps  etc....

Is my approach correct?
Can i use RS422/RS485 for interfaces other than UART?

Kindly suggest the best method(s).  Cost is not a big concern for me, time and reliability are in my interest.

Comment: Sounds like a 4-20 loop would do nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incremental encoder, so you have two signal lines plus maybe an index pulse, at a minimum.

You should be able to use RS422 or RS485 drivers (the latter can be constantly enabled) and receivers to send a differential signal over a few pairs. If you use shielded twisted pairs, **properly terminated**, it should be more than okay. If the EMI environment is hostile, consider isolation.

You could use inexpensive shielded Ethernet cable if that suits your other requirements.

Comment: @ Mr. SPEHRO PEFHANYL: Thanks for your reply. I have one more but similar query regarding Analog hall effect sensor interface.

Comment: @ Mr. SPEHRO PEFHANYL: Thanks for your reply. I have one more similar query regarding Analog hall effect sensor interface. Specifications are:  Sine wave whose magnitude varies from 1V to 4V . Maximum frequency 300Hz. Sensor max o/p current is:1.5mA Max. How to transfer this analog output to 10 meter long?? My idea is to use Op-Amp buffers, but not sure, whether Op-Amp can drive the cable capacitance or not? Request you to suggest reliable method.